# htaccess file does not rendering the get arguments properly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please consider the following code in `.htaccess`.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Set home page
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?con=stories&task=published [L]

RewriteRule ^(published|new)/?$ index.php?con=stories&task=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(published|new)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=stories&task=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

When I browse the `https://example.com/published/`, and In PHP the `print_r($_GET)` displays something like:

```
Array (
    [con] => stories
    [task] => published
)
```

**My problem is that I see/get the same result above when I browse the `https://example.com/published/?hello=world`.**

I am expecting like the following output:

```
Array (
    [con] => stories
    [task] => published
    [hell] => world
)
```

**What is the solution, please?**

Comment: You just need to add `QSA` flag in your rules wherever you are modifying query string.

Comment: It seems like it is working, Thank You. I can take it as an answer if you post it as the answer.